# Shift + Mouse Click Selenium Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to press shift+mouse click keys using Selenium WebDriver(JAVASCRIPT). I need to select multiple element in my script. Is there any way to do it?

I checked the Selenium libraries and found that selenium allows key press of special and functional keys only.

Comment: If you need to hold down shift, try using `keyDown(Keys.Shift);`

Comment: You'll probably need to create an Actions chain for this.  (shift key down, left-click each item, shift key up)...  however, this would usually open a link in a new window.  (Command is outside of DOM, browser gets the event unless overridden)   Selenium is limited to the DOM, so this may not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the driver object, this will do it:

```
    // See:
    // - https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#keyboard-actions
    // - https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/input_exports_Actions.html
    // - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/input.js
    let SHIFT = '\uE008'
    await browser.driver.actions({ bridge: true })
        .keyDown(SHIFT)
        .click()
        .keyUp(SHIFT)
        .perform()
```